# Can anyone give an example of sequence statement?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Are there any sequences s.t. $\{a_{n}\}^{\infty}_{n=1}$ and $\{b_{n}\}^{\infty}_{n=1}, b_{n}\neq0, \forall n$ which diverge, but $\{\frac{a_{n}}{b_{n}}\}^{\infty}_{n=1}$ converges to $0$.

I have tried to plug in a bunch of examples, but failing to come up with one.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: pick the numerator so that it goes to infinity and then make the pick the denominator so that it goes to infinity faster.  Does that help?

Comment: I figured this would be it... Now that I think about it, such a dumb question haha.

Comment: Glad to confirm your guess in that case.

Comment: Not dumb.  This stuff is subtle, especially at the beginning.

Comment: Yep. It's good to let others show you the basic tricks at first until you are confident in your intuition.

Answer (score 0):

$a_n = (-1)^n$ and $b_n =n$ should work.

Comment: Des $\frac{-1^{n}}{n}$ converge to 0? That's a little confusing to me. I understand that it approaches $0$, but doesn't the alternating $a_{n} \in \{-1/n... ,1/n....\}$ diverge?

Comment: Yes it converges to 0. The sequence of absolute values clearly converges to 0, hence so does the original sequence.